# Properties of first degree homogeneous functions

Tags: functions, economics

This is a math question, even if it may seem an economics one. I'll try to explain all the economics in this question.

I've got the following production function, where $Y$ is the product, $L$ is the labour used in production, while $K$ is the capital. The $M$ subscript just stands for "manifacturing sector".

$Y_M=f_M (L_M, K_M)$ (1)

which is assumed to be a first degree homogeneous function. With this assumption, we may write

$Y_M=L_M m (k_M)$ (2)

Where $k_M=\dfrac{K_M}{L_M}$ and $m$ is the average productivity of labour.

Which transformation has been performed in order to obtain (2) and what's the influence of the function's first-degree homogeneity in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A homogeneous function $f(x,y)$ of degree one is any function $f(x,y)$ which satisfies the rule $f(kx,ky)=kf(x,y)$, for any choice of $k$. In your case, you want to pull out the $x$ to the front as a multiplier.

Now note that $$f(x,y)=f(x,x(y/x))$$ and this last has the common factor $x$ in both variable positions, so that $x$ is ready to be "pulled out" like the $k$ was in the above definition. This means we have
$$f(x,y)=f(x,x(y/x))=xf(1,y/x).$$
We can now give a new name to the function $f(1,y/x)$ and say it is $g(u)$ where $u=y/x$. That is, to make it more clear, we can just *define* the function $g(u)$ in terms of the original $f(x,y)$ by the definition $g(u)=f(1,u)$. Then you will have $f(x,y)=xg(y/x)$.

To correspond things to your notation, drop the subscript $M$ on the $f$, let the numbers $L,K$ correspond to $x,y$, so that also $K/L$ corresponds to $y/x$. I hope that is something of the explanation you were looking for...

By the way, the reason this depends on homogeneous of specifically degree *one* is that, at the stage where the constant $k$ is moved in front, a homogeneous function of degree say 2 would satisfy $f(kx,ky)=k^2f(x,y)$, which doesn't match what you want.

Comment: Thanks. Almost clear, the only thing I don't understand is: where does that $m$ come from? It's the average product, so it should be $\frac{f(k)}{L}$

Comment: Dropping all the subscripts, since I have

$Y=f(K,L)$, I pull out the L and I get

$Y=Lf(\frac{K}{L}, 1)$

$Y=Lf(k)$

Comment: I think in your original description the letter $m$ is not a number but represents the name given to the function $f(x,1)$ or $f(1,x)$ [depending on which variable you choose to "pull out"]. So $m(x)$ is like the $g(x)$ in my "generic" description.